# MacBook display screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics

Is it possible to fix a MacBook Pro display glass for a cracked one of a MacBook unibody? Since they have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Per the fixit-store: There is only one LCD glass panel for each model in a similar era (providing the "screen size" spec matches).

So, yes, as long as they are of a similar year!

Comment: Please could you add a link to the FixIt store page mentioning this.